# Parse with fragments

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, parse-platform

I am receiving the following two related errors in eclipse:

```
 1) The method getIntent() is undefined for the type Fragment1
 2) The method setDefaultPushCallback(Context, Class<? extends Activity>) in the type PushService is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentActivity, Class<Fragment1>)
```

Below is the portion of the code where the errors takes place:

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container,
                false);

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

        // inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getActivity(), Fragment1.class);
```

If you need any clarification, let me know.

Comment: the second argument is supposed to be a `Class<? extends Activity>`. Typically, the activity you want to be started as a push callback. It could be `getActivity().getClass()`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)You cannot call `getIntent()` inside a Fragment as it's not an Activity and so one does not inherit Activity's methods/ You should try using `getActivity().getIntent()` if you are really sure that this is what you are looking for.

2)This method asks you for a Context and you are passing it an Activity, and then asks you for a class that extends an activity and you are passing it a fragment. For the first argument i would call `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` and as a second argument `getActivity()`.

Edit: Try casting the `getActivity()` like: `(Activity) getActivity()`

```
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(((Activity)getActivity()).getIntent());

// inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(((Activity)getActivity()).getApplicationContext(), ((Activity)getAcitivty()));
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Unfortunately the issue still persist, and I am receiving the same error.  It has been rewritten as such ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getAcitivty().getIntent());        
        // inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getActivity());
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

Comment: What do you mean by same issue? Some more details please?

Comment: For example, for the first issue, the getActivity() method is underline in red with the following error: The method getAcitivty() is undefined for the type Fragment1, and for the second issue the setDefaultCallBack is also underline in red with the following error: The method setDefaultPushCallback(Context, Class<? extends Activity>) in the type PushService is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentActivity, FragmentActivity)

Comment: Check the edit please and tell me if it's working now

Comment: thank you for your response. Sadly another issue came up with the first issue - The method trackAppOpened(Intent) in the type ParseAnalytics is not applicable for the arguments (Activity) and this is how it was written         ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened((Activity) getAcitivty().getIntent());

Comment: Let me rewrite your code and you use it per se!
Try using the code from Edit just copy-paste!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have used fragments in the past, and usually the solution is simple by refering getActivity() or getView() but the errros persist. For the first issue I have recieved the following message (Cannot cast from Intent to Activity) and the second issue retains the same error, below is the code      ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(((Activity)getActivity().getIntent());
     // inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(((Activity)getActivity()).getApplicationContext(), ((Activity)getActivity()));

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. This has resolve my first issue. For the second issue I unexpectedly received a different error:      The method setDefaultPushCallback(Context, Class<? extends Activity>) in the type PushService is not applicable for the arguments (Context, Activity)  and below was the code copied-paste      PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(((Activity)getActivity()).getApplicationContext(), ((Activity)getActivity()));

I appreciate your understanding

Comment: I can't really think of something else! Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for your support. lets see the first argument seems to be correct which context, where it differs is in the second argument in that right now it given an activity but it is requesting  a Class<? extends Activity> and on the documentation parse rights This should be a subclass of Activity. An instance of this Activity is started when
          the user responds to this push notification. If you are not sure what to use here,
          just use your application's main Activity subclass. https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/PushService.html

Comment: If it should be a subclass of an Activity then the FragmentActivity should work right and so on a simple getActivity() as a second argument would do it!

Comment: but then i unexpectedly receives the following error:  in the type PushService is not applicable for the arguments (Context, FragmentActivity)

Comment: Yeah you should contact Parse support or just try to clean your Project!

Comment: I think I may know the reason why the second argument couldn't work. I think it required me to reference another activity other than the current. Once I did, the issue has seem to be resolves such as      PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), anotherActivity.class);

Answer (score 1):

The two problems occur because you passed wrong parameters to them. Changes as following should help you get ride of them:

```
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getAcitivty().getIntent());

// inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getActivity(), getActivity());
```

But, whether this is what you want or not still depends on the needs of that two function.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Unfortunately the issue still persist, and I am receiving the same error. It has been rewritten as such ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getAcitivty().getIntent()); // inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getActivity()); ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();